# Typescript typing a function that takes an object with zero or more properties of another type?

Tags: typescript

I have a type

```
type Animal = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  dimensions: number[];
};
```

Now I want to make a function that lets me pass in an object with one or more of those fields but only those fields and only of the correct type. Example

```
type OnlyAnimalProps = Record<string, any>;  // bad

function createAnimal(parent: Animal, props: OnlyAnimalProps) {
   return {...parent, ...props};
}
```

So that these are ok

```
g1 = createAnimal(someAnimal, {});  // ok
g2 = createAnimal(someAnimal, {name: "Cindy"});  // ok
g3 = createAnimal(someAnimal, {age: 12, dimensions: [1, 3, 2]});  // ok
```

but these are not ok

```
e1 = createAnimal(someAnimal, {height: 123});  // bad, "height" doesn't exist
e2 = createAnimal(someAnimal, {name: 456});  // bad, name is not a number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

I know this answer must already exist but my searching hasn't brought up the answer

Comment: Presumably you're looking for [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) like [this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOAgMm) shows? Does that meet your needs or am I missing something? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: Yes @jcalz, that looks like it. Strange that react's setState is something like this `type AnimalSetterFn = <K extends keyof Animal>(     state:         | Animal         | ((prevState: Readonly<Animal>, props: Readonly<Props>) => Animal | Pick<Animal, K> | null)         | Pick<Animal, K>         | null,     callback?: (() => void) | undefined ) => void;` which doesn't mention `Partial` and yet takes partial object, none of which seem to fit that signature.

Comment: Making it generic in `K extends keyof Animal` with `Pick<Animal, K>` sidesteps an issue where `Partial<Animal>` would accept explicitly `undefined` properties like `{name: undefined}`. But without an explicit use case that mentions being concerned about that (I mean, really, who passes `undefined` in?) I would just use `Partial<Animal>`.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of expressing this is with [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) which [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) an object type `T` to a version where all the properties have been made [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties):

```
type PartialAnimal = Partial<Animal>;
/* type PartialAnimal = {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
    dimensions?: number[];
} */
```

So you can use `Partial<Animal>` as your `props` type:

```
function createAnimal(parent: Animal, props: Partial<Animal>) {
  return { ...parent, ...props };
}
```

Which works as desired for the examples you provided:

```
const someAnimal = { name: "Bob", age: 11, dimensions: [4, 2, 1] };

const g1 = createAnimal(someAnimal, {});  // ok
const g2 = createAnimal(someAnimal, { name: "Cindy" });  // ok
const g3 = createAnimal(someAnimal, { age: 12, dimensions: [1, 3, 2] });  // ok

const e1 = createAnimal(someAnimal, { height: 123 }); // error
const e2 = createAnimal(someAnimal, { name: 456 });  // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-1jQjNU6XQyBGMaB6HhBOb7uYShXrBXyReFOLCAKwANnlztdSakKbwQA)